# If my mail domain admin can check my activity through google business when I was logged in can I avoid them to do so by using a mail client?

Tags: email, user-tracking

I think it's secure to use log-in through a mail client like mail-spring.I think in this way we have separated the account just for mail.Can they still track my google search history.If anyone can track who is it???.Is it just google or other stuff can also my log.

Comment: This is a big jumble of concepts. You need to expand and explain a lot more. Who's the admin? What activity? Logged into what? What mail client? What accounts?

Comment: ok let me just clear that my university domain like something@universityname.edu.pk  ,I've logged in through gmail in browser ,and here I search something on google ,there is record will be available according to my search I've studied that it is available for domain .Domain admin or holder can see that.So is it secure to use mail client to keep them away to hold my search record.???I'm using   mailspring mail client ...activity means what I've searched on google during login session.

Comment: How do you search the Internet through Gmail or your mail client? You need a browser to do that. What browser are you using? Are you logged into your domain through the browser?

Comment: ohhh my god bro I'm doing so with browser but during search my I'm logged in in my gmail account.Nobody can search with gmail. I'm using google for search during my gmail account logged in is it clear now.Google holds record for each account record when anybody search during login  .and I did't searched with my mail client .mail client is just used for send and get mails and mail related things. Yes I am logged in my browser while searching the google other things .I just wanna clear that Now I'm signed out from browser and using mail spring for mails ,Can they now keep record of my search???